# How to create user and grant permission MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to create a new user on my MySql database and grant them view only permissions so they can look around and not actually be able to change anything. I've tried the following code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO users(user_name, password, admin) VALUES('" + usernameTextBox.Text + "','" + passwordTextBox.Text + "', '1')";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();


query = "CREATE USER '" + usernameTextBox.Text + "' IDENTIFIED BY '" + passwordTextBox.Text + "'";
command = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

query = "GRANT SELECT, SHOW DATABASES ON database.* TO '" + usernameTextBox.Text + "'@'%'";
command = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES

I've been trying to read the documentation of MySql and reading other questions here on Stack Overflow, however I cannot seem to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

The CREATE USER, FILE, PROCESS, RELOAD, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, **SHOW DATABASES**, SHUTDOWN, and SUPER privileges are administrative and can only be granted globally. 
**It cannot be applied to a single database** 
you need split grant query

```
GRANT SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%'; -- GRANT TO ALL DATABASES
GRANT SELECT ON database.*  TO 'username'@'%';
```

P.S. and your code is not safety for SQL Injection, you have to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 0):

grant permission in **MySQL** or MariaDB

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DatabaseName.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`